# How to integrate Stripe payment in Ionic 4

Tags: stripe-payments, angular7, ionic4

I am new in ionic framework and trying to integrate stripe in my app.
I did some research and found only this https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe. It doesn't explain well enough. How can i implement the concept on .html file like to provide a user with a button to trigger the payment?

I also tried this https://fireship.io/lessons/stripe-elements-angular/ but got lost along the way.

### checkout.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
// import { Stripe } from '@ionic-native/stripe/ngx';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

declare var Stripe;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rentals',
  templateUrl: './rentals.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rentals.page.scss'],
})
export class RentalsPage implements OnInit {

  user$: Observable<User>;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
      // private stripe: Stripe, 
      private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
      private auth: AuthService, 
      private functions: AngularFireFunctions
        ) 
    { 

    }


    @Input() amount;
    @Input() description;

    handler: StripeCheckoutHandler;

    confirmation: any;
    loading = false;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_3PyCxdSZ21lC5Wg7lOs2gyF8',
      image: '/assets/icon/favicon.png',
      locale: 'auto',
      source: async (source) => {
        this.loading = true;
        const user = await this.firebaseService.User();
        const fun = this.functions.httpsCallable('stripeCreateCharge');
        this.confirmation = await fun({ source: source.id, uid: user.uid, amount: this.amount }).toPromise();
        this.loading = false;

      }
    });
    }

    // Open the checkout handler
    async checkout(e) {
    const user = await this.auth.getUser();
    this.handler.open({
      name: 'Fireship Store',
      description: this.description,
      amount: this.amount,
      email: user.email,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Close on navigate
    @HostListener('window:popstate')
    onPopstate() {
    this.handler.close();
    }

}
```

### checkout.page.html

```
<ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
         <img *ngIf="!fileUrl" src="assets/1.jpeg"/>
        <ion-card-subtitle>Bed Sitter</ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="id">{{ plan_Et8WWHlFFGNxym }}</ion-input>
        <ion-card-title>KSH4,000.00 Monthly</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>

      <ion-card-content>
        bed sitter flat
      </ion-card-content>

      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="amount">{{ 4000 }}</ion-input>
        <ion-button slot="end" color="primary" (click)="checkout($event)">Pay 4000.00</ion-button>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

### auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { FirebaseService } from './firebase.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ){}


  doRegister(value){
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
     .then(
       res => resolve(res),
       err => reject(err))
   })
  }

  doLogin(value){
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
     firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
     .then(
       res => resolve(res),
       err => reject(err))
   })
  }

  doLogout(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
      .then(() => {
        this.firebaseService.unsubscribeOnLogOut();
        resolve();
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject();
      });
    })
  }
}
```

I expect the code to fetch subscription plans from stripe or as i have input manually on the code above, to post the payment with the stated plan to stripe.

Comment: this was quite a while ago, did you ever get it figured out?

Comment: I haven't used the plugin I just used the web version for Ionic and it works great.  It is very easy to get up and running.  Use stripe checkout if you want it all done for you but to be less configurable and you can't save customers or cards.  If you want more control use Stripe elements but you have to build everything yourself.  I can give you a code example if you are interested.  Here is a basic example:  https://fireship.io/lessons/stripe-elements-angular/